# Does unlocking shared lock in one transaction depend on the shared lock that is given after that in another transaction?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, locking

I need to show that if two transactions hold a shared lock on a table, the latter cannot be dropped from within the one taken the lock last.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Share Table Locks (S)
```

A share table lock is acquired automatically for the table specified in the following statement:

```
LOCK TABLE table IN SHARE MODE;
```

Below are the Permitted Operations:

- A `share table lock` held by a transaction allows other transactions only to
  to `SELECT` (query the table)
- to lock specific rows with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
- or to execute LOCK TABLE ... IN SHARE MODE

statements successfully.

No updates are allowed by other transactions. Multiple transactions can hold share table locks for the same table concurrently. In this case, no transaction can update the table (even if a transaction holds row locks as the result of a `SELECT` statement with the `FOR UPDATE clause`). Therefore, a transaction that has a share table lock can update the table only if no other transactions also have a share table lock on the same table.

If you want an example you can refer below link:

http://oracledbascriptsfromajith.blogspot.com/2011/10/oracle-locking.html